# What is the direct URL for Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, ssh

Trying to retrieve CE 1.9.2.2 directly via ssh however 
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.2.2/magento-1.9.2.2.tar.gz
is returning a not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no direct link unless you login to website or repository.
you have 3 options:
1- login to magento account and go to downloads page.
2- using your magento ID and downloads token call this from the server:

```
curl https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/help
```

3- you can use this script to configure empty server:

```
https://github.com/magenx/MASC-M
```